# Change the location of the node_modules folder

Tags: asp.net, npm, visual-studio-2015, node-modules, vs-web-site-project

I'm currently trying to migrate an old ASP.NET WebSite project to Visual Studio 2015. I'd like to use NPM/Gulp to automatically compile LESS files to CSS (this task was done by WebEssentials in VS 2013).

I added a `package.json` file to the project to load the required components. This creates a `node_modules` folder in the root of the WebSite project, and this is where my problem starts:

Since WebSite projects don't have a project file, all files (and sub-directories) found in the project root folder, are automatically part of the project. Due to the deeply nested directory structure inside `node_modules`, this leads to errors because of too long path names.

An easy workaround is to set the `hidden` attribute on the `node_modules` folder (but this has to be done manually by each developer).

Is there a way to tell NPM to put the node modules into another directory e.g. one level above the project (`..\node_modules`) where the solution file is?

Or is it possible to set the hidden attribute on a folder from a gulp-task (which runs when the project is loaded)?

Comment: You can approach the problem the other way around. Create your website root in a different location, and use gulp to compile sources and write them to your website folder (i.e. `public`)
then run npm/gulp from your solution directory, and let your entry point of your website point to the `public` folder.

Comment: @Rik: I'm not sure that's possible with an ASP.NET *WebSite* project, but I will think about it. Also, if possible, I'd rather not make too many changes to that old project.

Comment: But you are adding the npm files somewhere. pick any location that is not in your website folder and use `gulp.src().pipe(dostuff).gulp.dest(path/to/website/dir)` from there.
With gulp.dest() you can copy the files to any location. Doesn't need any structural changes.

Comment: Thanks @Rik, that worked. NPM/Gulp can also be added at the solution-level (not only at project-level).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on @Rik's answer, I was able to solve the problem:

Instead of adding the `package.json` and `gulpfile.js` into the WebSite project, I added them at the solution level (as solution items). This means, that the `node_modules` folder is now in the solution directory at the same level as the WebSite project(s).

The only other change was to modify the paths in `gulpfile.js` accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to check out npm 3.0+. It installs the modules in a maximally flat structure. It should reduce the paths lengths in the module directory.

From the release notes

> Flat, flat, flat!
>
> Your dependencies will now be installed maximally flat. Insofar as is
>   possible, all of your dependencies, and their dependencies, and THEIR
>   dependencies will be installed in your project's node_modules folder
>   with no nesting. You'll only see modules nested underneath one another
>   when two (or more) modules have conflicting dependencies.
>
> - **#3697** This will hopefully eliminate most cases where windows users ended up with paths that were too long for Explorer and other
>     standard tools to deal with.
> - **#6912** (#4761 #4037) This also means that your installs will be deduped from the start.
> - **#5827** This deduping even extends to git deps.
> - **#6936** (#5698) Various commands are dedupe aware now.
>
> This has some implications for the behavior of other commands:
>
> - npm uninstall removes any dependencies of the module that you    specified that aren't required by any other module. Previously, it
>     would only remove those that happened to be installed under it,
>     resulting in left over cruft if you'd ever deduped.
> - npm ls now shows you your dependency tree organized around what    requires what, rather than where those modules are on disk.
> - **#6937** npm dedupe now flattens the tree in addition to deduping.

https://github.com/npm/npm/releases/tag/v3.0.0

For upgrading the windows installation check out this package npm-windows-upgrade

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/10565078)

Comment: Added more detail to the answer